# Updated command to start blank project with ionic2 and angular2?

Tags: android, angular, sqlite, cordova, ionic2

Trying to create blank project with ionic2 not ionic1 or ionic3 using the below command in terminal

```
ionic start SqliteDemo blank --type ionic2
```

Error comes as below:

```
✔ Creating directory ./SqliteDemo - done!
✖ Looking up starter - failed!
[ERROR] Unable to find starter template for blank

        If this is not a typo, please make sure it is a valid starter template 
        within the starters repo: https://github.com/ionic-team/starters
```

what i have tried ?

```
ionic start SQliteDemo blank --v2
```

not worked
all above commands just create Folder for the given name and nothing is inside.

Actually Trying:
I need to work with sqlite storage/ with any android native api's, as first attempt i try to do a sample project based on sqlite so that i can add android platform to this project and open with Android-Studio and check whether the .db file is created and working or not using Android-Monitor. If any references for this question will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What version of Ionic are you using? (type ionic --v) on cmd

Comment: i'm using ionic 3.19.1